# Foreground thread don't stop a console process from terminating?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

In the following WPF code, once button is clicked, a new foreground thread is started. Then I close the WPF window, I could see that in Windows task manager, the process won't be terminated until `Thread.Sleep(100000)` ends. I could understand it because foreground threads could prevent process from terminating as MSDN doc says.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(Go).Start();
    }

    private void Go(object obj)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

But when I try almost the same thing in a console program, the process terminates immediately after I close the console window. Anybody could help to explain the differences?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(Go).Start();
    }

    private static void Go()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But when I try almost the same thing in a console program, the process terminates immediately after I close the console window. Anybody could help to explain the differences?

---

**TL; DR;** The difference is that it is a console app and you are clicking the **close box**.  It's pretty similar to nuking it from *Task Manager*.  Additionally, **all console app primary threads are foreground threads** too.  See example at end of this answer.

---

If you click the close box on a console app, Windows will kill all thread and shutdown your console app regardless of whether the threads are background or foreground.   For a GUI app such as WinForms or WPF; the rule of *"Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process"* applies. There is no direct link between clicking the close box on a GUI app and process termination, unlike console apps

If you run the following code in the debugger, it will wait for the other thread to complete.  However, **clicking the close box nukes the process and control returns to** *Visual Studio* thus **proving the process really did exit** and isn't playing hide-and-seek like Windows Forms can do with foreground threads. (closing a WinForms main app window with foreground threads still running just closes the window, not necessarily the process)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(Go).Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread {0} exiting", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
        }

        private static void Go()
        {
            var thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} thread {1} sleeping",thread.IsBackground ? "Background" : "Foreground",  thread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(100000);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Assuming you don't click on the close box then the console app won't terminate until all threads are finished.

MSDN:

> Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process

### An easy way to prove things

You can prove this console app behavior by simply:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} thread {1} sleeping", thread.IsBackground ? "Background" : "Foreground", thread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(100000);
}
```

Now we're not spawning any new threads here but a simple click of the close box is sufficient to send the process to oblivion.  But wait, did you see that the **main thread is in fact a foreground thread**?

[image]

Comment: The main thread is a foreground thread, and I do click the close box to close the console program. Thanks for you answer, more clear now!

Comment: But one more question, when I click the close box on a WPF window, why Windows doesn't kill the process?

Comment: @UncannyAxe No worries.  For a GUI app such as WinForms or WPF;  the rule of _"Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process"_ applies.  There is no direct link between clicking the close box on a GUI app and process termination, unlike console apps